# What is the best practice to delete intermediate pointers generated in nested function calls?

Tags: c, design-patterns, matrix, destructor

I am writing a basic matrix library in c, and the matrix data structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct Matrix{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double complex *matrix;
} Matrix;
```

and the corresponding function to initialize the matrix and the function to free the pointer(similar to constructor and destructor in c++)

```
Matrix* InitializeMatrix(int r, int c){
    Matrix* mat = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    mat->rows = r;
    mat->cols = c;
    mat->matrix = (double complex *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(double complex));
    return mat;
}

int DeleteMatrix(Matrix *mat){
    mat->rows = 0;
    mat->cols = 0;
    free(mat->matrix);
    mat->matrix = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the main problem. Suppose I have two functions

```
Matrix* fun1(Matrix* input){
    //some operations
    Matrix* mat = InitializeMatrix(r, c);
    //some operations
    return mat;
}
Matrix* fun2(Matrix* input){
    //some operations
    Matrix* mat = InitializeMatrix(r, c);
    //some operations
    return mat;
}
```

Now I have another function want to nest `fun1`and `fun2`

```
Matrix* fun3(Matrix* input){
    return fun2(fun1(input));
}
```

Usually when I call a function, I will have to call `DeleteMatrix` to free the memory, but in `fun2(fun1(input))`, the reference to the matrix generated by `fun1(input)` is not saved, and cannot be freed. I know I can create a intermediate variable to make that reference, but I would like to keep nested function calls since it is neat and intuitive. Is there a problem in my overall design? How to overcome this problem?

Comment: The facetious answer is that you can do this in C++ using destructors. I don't think you can use the nested pattern easily in C, unless you signal to your functions somehow that they now own the memory passed to it.

Comment: @Bathsheba yep, my original project is in c++, for some purpose I have to write a C version, then this problem arose.

Comment: To those down voters: please leave a comment to address the problem. Otherwise what is your purpose to down vote? To show off your knowledge level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that but it create intermediary function:

```
Matrix* use_and_free(Matrix* input, Matrix* (*fct)(Matrix *)) {
  Matrix* ret = fct(input);
  DeleteMatrix(input);
  return ret;
}

Matrix* fun3(Matrix* input){
    return use_and_free(fun1(input), &fun2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to change the function prototypes so that `fun1()` and `fun2()` take a second argument that is a pointer to a `Matrix`. Then you can change the bodies of the functions so that a new `Matrix` is allocated if this argument is `NULL`, otherwise the `output` `Matrix` is used. For example:

```
Matrix* fun1(Matrix* input, Matrix* output){
    //some operations
    Matrix* mat;
    if (output == NULL){
        mat = InitializeMatrix(input->rows, input->cols);
    } else {
        mat = output;
    }
    //some operations
    return mat;
}
```

Here I presume that the `r` and `c` of your original function, which were undeclared, referred to the number of rows and columns of the `input` `Matrix`. If you want `fun1()` to allocate a new `Matrix`, call it like this:

```
Matrix* result = fun1(input, NULL);
```

If you want to use a preallocated `Matrix`:

```
Matrix* mtrx = InitializeMatrix(3, 3);
mtrx = fun1(input, mtrx);
```

And if you want to chain together `fun1()` and `fun2()`:

```
mtrx = fun2(fun1(input, mtrx), mtrx);
```

Although it would probably be better to let the outer function call do the allocation; this way `mtrx` is always an intermediate result, and you only need to create a new `Matrix` pointer to get a new result. Note that you will still have to allocate space for `mtrx`:

```
result = fun2(fun1(input, mtrx), NULL);
```

You could chain even more functions together, but this may cross the threshold into impropriety:

```
result = fun3(fun2(fun1(input, mtrx), mtrx), NULL);
```

Also, note that your `DeleteMatrix()` function is faulty. There is no need to zero out the fields, and you need to `free(mat)` as well as `free(mat->matrix)`:

```
int DeleteMatrix(Matrix* mat){
    free(mat->matrix);
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not shown how the input argument is used. Decide, who owns the allocated Matrix. Would this do? (assuming ownership is transferred to fun2)

```
Matrix* fun2(Matrix* input){
    //some operations
    Matrix* mat = InitializeMatrix(r, c);
    //some operations
    DeleteMatrix(input);
    return mat;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Normally I will keep the input matrix as well, i.e. I want both the original matrix and the transposed matrix. I would directly modify the input matrix if it is not necessary to keep the input.

Comment: Ah,OK, I get your intent now. I think David Bowling above has the answer.